# javascript onclick function undefined internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, undefined

It's been few hours that I'm looking for an issue for this problem. 
My javascript code works well on Chrome, firefox and edge but it doesn't work on internet explorer. 
The function is undefined on internet explorer. I know that there is already a lot of topic about it but no of them work in my case.

```js
function it_do_not_work() 
{
   alert('Not working');
}
```

```html
<div class="submit-petsitter-selection">
  <input type="submit" id="submit-petsitter-selection" class="btn btn-red-search" name="PetSittersSelection" data-selected-petsitters-none="@Translation.C03b_NumberOfSelectedPetSittersNone" data-selected-petsitters-singular="@Translation.C03_NumberOfSelectedPetSittersSingular" data-selected-petsitters-plural="@Translation.C03a_NumberOfSelectedPetSittersPlural" onclick="it_do_not_work();" />
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo but you have two opening <script> elements and no closing </script>?

Comment: I mistyped, but I didn't forget it in the project ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was a compatibility of internet Explorer. I added :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You do realise that [conditional comments are deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: The whole point of the conditional comment is to do nothing in IE9 and above. So it really doesn't matter that IE10 won't evaluate it.